# Babeljs produces unexpected error for regex {m,n} quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I have the following:

```
const checkCode = code => {
    if( /^\+[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{3}[A-Z]+[0-9]{3}$/.test( code ))){
        return true;
    }
    //run more code...
}
```

Babel transpiler produces an unexpected token error pointing at the first **{** of the regular expression as in:

```
if( /^\+[0-9]{
             ^
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in the transpiler. Can you do `var regex = new Regex('^\+[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}[A-Z]+[0-9]{3}$')` and then do `if(regex.test(code)) { // do stuff }`?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you switch to `if( code.match(/^\+[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}[A-Z]+[0-9]{3}$/)) {`?

Comment: Can you post your `.babelrc` settings and the versions of all of the installed babel plugins/presets/etc?

Comment: You have extra parens at the end of `if` it transpiles fine for me after removing that..

Comment: you've misinterpreted where the error is

Comment: Thank you, guys. I just found and fixed a typo in the regexp. So the code  now reflects the code that was causing the error

Answer (score 1):

The babel error might point at a weird token, but you clearly have some typos/mistakes in that line:

```
    if( /^\+[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{3}[A-Z]+[0-9]{3}$/.test( code ))){
//                  ^                                      ^
```

Comment: The pattern requires the "/" character though. I had already removed the extra parens but the compiler error has not gone away.

Comment: @000: It's not only the extra parenthesis but also the slash. You should escape it [as you originally did](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38669468/2)

Answer (score 0):

After removing the extra parenthesis, the compiler error continued. I then escaped the "/" in the pattern and the error disappeared.

Since javascript engine uses "/" to denote the beginning and the ending of a regex pattern that unescaped "/" within the pattern sent the wrong message. Why the transpiler places the error marker at the quantifier character is unclear.